# Set initramfs to prompt for luks passowrd on startup on Mint 18?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub, initramfs

After updating to Mint 18.1, I can't get initramfs to prompt for a password to unlock the volume with the root file system on it. I have to wait until initramfs times out to a prompt then run `cryptsetup luksOpen` manually.

I've tried running `update-initramfs` while the system is mounted and running (as well as from the live CD in chroot) and I have an entry in `/etc/crypttab`.

This was working for me before the Mint 18 upgrade, but for some reason I'm still not getting a password prompt now no matter what I try.

What should I check?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The UUID in `/etc/crypttab` has to be the UUID of the device that the crypt container sits on top of, not the UUID of the container. Or in other words, if you have `/dev/sda1` with `/dev/mapper/sda1_crypt` on top of it, the `/etc/crypttab` file should contain the name of the mapper device, `sda1_crypt` with the UUID of `/dev/sda1` **not** the UUID of `/dev/mapper/sda1_crypt`.

An `/etc/crypttab` entry should look like this (all four fields are required):

```
 mappedname UUID=12345678-9abc-def012345-6789abcdef01 none luks
```

You can get the UUID's from the `blkid` command.

After this, `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

Comment: This is good to know - is it possible do the unlocking directly in GRUB through the luks module?  Additionally, it would allow the user to re-use the same image across multiple devices whilst only needing to update the parameters on the GRUB cmdline.

Comment: Small addendum: if the underlying device is an SSD, you may want `luks,discard` in the last field rather than simply `luks`. (This leaks some usage-pattern metadata through the encryption; see warning in the manpage. But it can help out your SSD a lot.)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script to partially automate this by mounting the partition and checking this file and then unmounting and remounting the encrypted partition with the correct name so the `update-initramfs` call works correctly.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467113/103652

I could paste that or the script here again, but I'd hate to start skewing the versions between Q&As. The gist where the script (and any updates to it) lives is https://gist.github.com/dragon788/e777ba64d373210e4f6306ad40ee0e80